# Select from Contacts a List of People Based on Email Label Using AppleScript

Tags: email, label, applescript, contacts

Using AppleScript, how do I get a list of all people in the Contacts application who have at least one email address with a particular label?

I tried:

`set peopleToCheck to every person where ((label of its email contains strContactEmailLabelHome))`

Unfortunately, it returns an empty set.  This can’t be correct because

`set peopleToCheck to every person where ((label of its first email contains strContactEmailLabelHome))`

Returns a set of one person.

Answer (score 0):

```
set customLabel to "customLabel"

tell application "Contacts"
    return people whose label of emails contains customLabel
end tell
```

Or, using **variable** for the list:

```
set customLabel to "customLabel"

tell application "Contacts"
    set theList to people whose label of emails contains customLabel
end tell

return theList
```

Comment: Oh.  I’ve never seen `return` used to create a list.  This appears to select people based on the label of only their *first* email.  



I want to create a set of people based on the label of *any* of their emails.  I don’t think this answer addresses my question.  Please accept my apology if I’ve misunderstood what it does.

Comment: Re: @Nello Lucchesi. Very inetresting. Nice. You yourself asked  the 1st email of persons, and now you have changed your question. See your script - it asks for the 1st emails of persons. As for the fact that **return** does not return lists, imagine - it returns.

Answer (score 0):

```
property text item delimiters : linefeed

tell application id "com.apple.AddressBook"
    -- Get the label of every email of every person
    get label of people's emails as text
    set labels to the result's text items
    
    -- Remove duplicate items from the list of email labels
    tell (a reference to the labels)
        repeat length times
            if string 1 = "" then set string 1 to 0
            if string 1 is not in rest of strings then set end to string 1
            set string 1 to 0
        end repeat
        set contents to strings
    end tell
    
    labels --> List of unique labels currently in use by at least one contact
    
    -- Choose a label to match contacts against
    set [specificLabel] to choose from list of labels ¬
        with title ["Search Contacts by Email Label"] ¬
        with prompt ["Select one of your email labels:"] ¬
        OK button name ["Search"] cancel button name ["Close"] ¬
        without multiple selections allowed and empty selection allowed
    
    -- Matches
    set P to a reference to (every person ¬
        whose emails's label contains ¬
        the specificLabel)
    
    
    -- Select the matching contacts in the application
    set selection to P
    
    return name of P
end tell
```